# How to exclude NoneType class while reading string in Python

Tags: python

I have a list that is pulled into python from Google Sheets.
Some of the cells are empty and return a value of None.

I checked the class type for these 'None' values and it says class = 'NoneType'

What is the best way to exclude these cells, without loosing the the "i coordinate" of the cells that do contain the string values i'm interested in?

This is what I tried, but i'm getting a syntax error:

```
for i, val in enumerate(some_list):
    if ( i != isinstance(NoneType))
        print (i,val)
```

Comment: Just `if val:` will work.

Comment: @Jkdc This would also filter out cells with `0` value

Comment: The syntax is `isinstance(variable, type)` but anyway, Alastair's solution is correct.

Comment: @dhke They're almost certainly going to be strings, `'0'` is True

Comment: @Jkdc The question clearly states that there are `None` values that should be filtered, not anything else.

Comment: This is true - there might be 0 - which is good data that I want to keep. I don't want to calculate no values however.

Comment: See my update, which adds empty string/blank checking too

Comment: The syntax error is that the `if` statement needs to end with a `:`.

Comment: Great thank you so much! Also - as i'm new to this community, could someone tell me why the question was down-voted? Should I word the questions differently in the future? Or was it subject matter related?

Comment: I didn't down vote. The only problem I see is that you didn't include the traceback for the syntax error, which shows the problem area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for i, val in enumerate(some_list):
    if val is not None:
        print (i,val)
```

If you wish to skip None **and** blank values:

```
for i, val in enumerate(some_list):
    if val is not None and val != "":
        print (i,val)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I'm new to Python but I guess I need to stop over thinking it - very straight forward thanks!

Comment: It only removes `None` values. If you want zeroes (and empty strings) filtered, just use `if val:` as suggested elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In case, when gapes in `i` are not needed:

```
for i, val in enumerate([x for x in some_list if x]):
    ...
```

Comment: This looses the index position as you are skipping the value. OP states he needs the original indexes.